# Sails.js - move api functions to a shared file

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I want to move some api functions to the shared file and have access to this functions from different controllers. The structure have to look like this:

[image]

How can I do it using Sails.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Services](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/services.md) are designed for this purpose.

> Services are basically libraries, which contain functions that you
>   might want to use in many places of your application.